# IronOCR Tesseract "Translate symbol to string"

Tags: c#, tesseract

I would like to know if it was possible to use IronOCR Tesseract to "translate" symbol to string. Actually, IronOCR Tesseract only analyse characters. But maybe, we can do traineddata to make him understand symbol. I give you an example pic : I would like iron ocr tesseract return me "attack" when analysing this symbol [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kX42S.png)

Comment: Tesseract can't do this. Maybe you can train a image recognition software for that, try [this](https://teachablemachine.withgoogle.com/) website.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion @osfresia, but how do I generate thousands of images to use this tool ?